# Why does whois command not work work with the www prefix when writing the URL

Tags: dns, whois

When we use `whois` suppose `whois www.netflix.com` shows that there is no match for the website in the whois database.

But this works when we use `whois netflix.com`.

Answer (score 2):

Only the top-level domain is registered in whois. `www` is a subdomain, which are handled by the domain owner's DNS services. They are independent of each other; see [DNS Resolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System#Address_resolution_mechanism) for more info.